# Having F# FAKE inject version into project.json of ASP .NET 5 project

Tags: f#, asp.net-core, f#-3.0, f#-fake

My team uses F# FAKE scripts for its build scripts across all our projects.  We have recently begun working with ASP .NET 5, but have not figured out how to inject the build version number into the project's project.json file the way you can with the AssemblyInfo.cs file in non-ASP .NET 5 projects.  Anyone come up with a solution with how to inject the version as part of the continuous integration process?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any specific function to work with `project.json` file in FAKE itself but you can try using `RegexReplaceInFileWithEncoding` (http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-filehelper.html) to replace `version` attribute via regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can the `DNX_BUILD_VERSION` environment variable to set the package version. That will make `dnx` replace the `*` in version in `project.json` with a particular version: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime/ProjectReader.cs#L36-L51

For example, if the `project.json` file has:

```
"version": "1.0.0-*"
```

and you set `DNX_BUILD_VERSION` to `beta-23` then the final version will be `1.0.0-beta-23`

However, I don't think we have any support for fully replacing the version with something different. It only works when you have a `*` version.

Then, you can use `DNX_ASSEMBLY_FILE_VERSION` to set the `AssemblyFileVersion` attribute: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime/ProjectReader.cs#L53-L72. This one supports full replacement.